# symmetric matrix rank and leading minor

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix with rank $r$. Is it true that there exists at least one non-zero $r\times r$ leading minor .

Here, a $r\times r$ leading minor  is the determinate of a submatrix of $A$ with rows and columns from $i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_r$.

It is easy that if $A$ is a real matrix, then it is right....However, for other fields, I do not whether this is right...

Comment: For complex field it is also true.

Comment: @timon Could you please tell me why? thank you.

Comment: In that case using spectral theorem for normal matrix you will get a unitary matrix U so that U*AU =D where D is diagonal matrix with r non zero diagonal entry which are precisely non zero eigenvalue of A.

Comment: @timon How can we see that $D$ is diagonal, we can see $D$ is only jordan carnonical form. How about the problem for any field? Thank you.

Comment: Search for spectral theorem for normal  or symmetric matrices you will get the proof. For arbitrary field I don't know what would be the answer.